# Can we control animation based on a set of data points?

Tags: javascript, animation, graph, 3d

I have a set of 300 data points which is the distance travelled in every 10ms. It's an experimental result, so there is no exact equation for the graph. Can we animate an object to travel in X direction in such a way, it reads the data points and move accordingly. The data points are not linear.

Comment: Are you looking to do this with java or javascript, and what's the environment?

Comment: Javascript. I am using eclipse to run javascript. I made my graphs with Chart.js. It creates the graph, But I want to show my experimental results in an animation, Like moving an object

Comment: You are going to need to define how you want the object to move a little better than "in X direction" and "accordingly".  Give some example datapoints and what the expected movement would be.

Comment: Let's say a wheel is moving in ground and tiles. When it moves in ground, the distance it travelled in experiment every 10ms for 100 ms in X,Y coordinates is [1,0], [2,0], [2,0], [2,0], [2,0], [2,0], [3,0], [3,0], [3,0], [1,0]. When it moves in tiles, the distance it travelled in experiment every 10ms for 100 ms in X,Y coordinates is [1,0], [2,0], [3,0], [3,0], [3,0], [2,0], [3,0], [2,0], [2,0], [1,0]. I want to show this in animation like showing a ball moving in beach and ball moving in tiles, with this dataset

Answer (score 0):

I took a look at the [chart.js documentation](http://www.chartjs.org/docs/#advanced-usage) and it looks like there's an update method that will refresh your graph after you've made changes to it. if you're just looking to animate 1 point with 300 different single points, you could probably just do a timeout looping through the results:

```
var myBubbleChart = new Chart(ctx, {
    type: 'bubble',
    data: data,
    options: options
});

getData() //some method to obtain the datapoints
    .then(function (result) {

        for (var i = 0; i < result.length; i++) {
            setTimeout(function (myBubbleChart, result) {
                myBubbleChart.data.datasets[0].data[0] = result;
                myBubbleChart.update();
            }, 10 * i, myBubbleChart, result[i]);
        }

});
```

i haven't tested this code, it's just an example of how I think you could accomplish what you're looking for.